# check for element presence in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page in which i have to search for presence of element depending on first input in the first form only

```
<input type="text" /><!-- first input -->
<button></button>
<div>
    <form><input value="3" /></form> <!-- first form -->
    <form><input value="3" /></form>
</div>
```

and script

```
$("button").click(function()
{
    if( $(this).next().children("form").first().has("input[value='" + $(this).prev().val() + "']") )
        alert("Present");
    else
        alert("Absent");
});
```

But it's not working

Comment: if you assign some id it would be easier find the element references... are you in control of markup?

Comment: Inferred from your code is that you want to compare the contents of the first two inputs to ensure they match exactly.  IS that correctly assumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the [`.has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/) doesn't return a boolean, it returns a jQuery object, specifically it "constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements". You need to check the length of that object to see if any elements matched:

```
if($(this).next().children("form").first()
           .has("input[value='"+$(this).prev().val()+"']").length != 0)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mmQHB/

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: You're welcome. Note that although using the `.has()` method in the correct way gets you past your current problem, concatenating a user-entered value from a field directly into your jQuery selector isn't going to work if the user enters a quotation mark. Also I have a suspicion that the `"input[value='...']"` selector may only select against the original value attribute's value and not the current value of the input (at least, that's what seemed to be happening when I tried it in Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

You can check the presence of an element by checking the length of the collection a query returns:

For example, if i were to check if i had forms:

```
var forms = $('form').length //0 if none, at least 1 if any
```

Comment: i have one more div not listed here which has also some dynamic code